# how to add dynamic image in crystal report with out using databse?

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

Make sure you have a directory of images either on your shared or local drive (E.g. "C:\Images\")

2) Go to Insert > OLE Object > select Bitmap Image or Paintbrush Picture

3) Right-click the image and select Format Graphic > Picture tab > Click on the Formula button (X-2) beside 'Graphic Location' and put in a formula that reads image locations from the directory.

but in picture  tab no option like formula button.
plz suggest me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please reference the image I attached below.  Are you saying you do not see what I have highlighted in yellow?

This would be the appropriate area to set the location of your images based on how you are implementing the images.  Click on the X-2 button and select the field which will have your URL.

Does this help?

[image]